# Spring Boot Gradle mutli-module project controllers mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, architecture

I'm facing this kind of problem: I want to use the following architecure in my project:

`-root
  |-core
  |-proj2
  |-proj3`

so I have 3 separate modules. I wanted the modules proj2 and proj3 to be kind of facades with unique Controllers, however both of them should inherit from core project, where services and daos would be located so that I can `@Autowire` them. Now when I place `Application.java` containing `@SpringBootApplication` in core module, controllers from other's are not scanned by Spring. I tried `@ComponentScan` annotation, however it didn't resolve my problem.
The question is, does that idea make any sense? If yes, then how to resolve the controllers' mapping issue?

**EDIT:**
More complex tree:

`+demo
   |+core
      |-src
         |-main/java/com/demo/DemoApplication.java
         |-core.gradle 
   |+proj1
      |-src
         |-main/java/com/demo/controller/DemoController.java
         |-proj1.gradle
   |+proj2
   |-build.gradle`

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    group = 'com.example'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

project(':proj1') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
    }
}

project(':proj2') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
    }
}
```

core.gradle, proj1.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile(
            [group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: springBootVersion],
            [group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springBootVersion],
    )
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

DemoController.java

```
package com.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public String testMethod() {
        return "Inside test method";
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code. gradle build, application class, controllers. With their package statement.